# Is there Any Way to Convert Mongo ObjectId into string by javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, c#

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to convert mongo objectId into string.

The above pictures shows data i received and shown in console.I need id value in string form .but ObjectId is returning as object

In Database id is look like this- 565d3bf4cefddf1748d1fc5e -objectId and i need id exactly like this –

Comment: What are you using to serialize your json? json.net? And what would you like the id to look like in the end

Comment: In Database id is look like this- 565d3bf4cefddf1748d1fc5e -objectId and i need id exactly like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Mongo documentation:

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- a 3-byte machine identifier,
- a 2-byte process id, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

You can check it out here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

So in javascript you could do something like this.

```
var mId = {
    Timestamp:1448950573,
    Machine:13565407,
    Pid:1756,
    Increment:8888962
};

function getId(mongoId) {
    var result = 
        pad0(mongoId.Timestamp.toString(16), 8) +
        pad0(mongoId.Machine.toString(16), 6) +
        pad0(mongoId.Pid.toString(16), 4) +
        pad0(mongoId.Increment.toString(16), 6);

    return result;
}

function pad0(str, len) {
    var zeros = "00000000000000000000000000";
    if (str.length < len) {
        return zeros.substr(0, len-str.length) + str;
    }

    return str;
}

console.log(getId(mId))
```

It produces "565d3b2dcefddf06dc87a282" which was not exactly the id you had, but that might just be a tweak or i was working with different data :D.

**EDIT**
Added a padding function so that zeros are not truncated.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks verymuch ,it works 90%,but there is problem this is the string i got from your function 565d3af1cefddf6dc87a281 but actuall objectid is this
                              565d3af1cefddf06dc87a281 there is change in 14 place

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I assume you are using c# to connect to and serve documents from the mongo DB. In that case, there is a driver that also supports [toString()](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_ObjectId.htm).

Here is an example using the [mongo csharp driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/examples/exporting_json/):

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.IO;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Driver;

// ...

string outputFileName; // initialize to the output file
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection; // initialize to the collection to read from

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputFileName))
{
    await collection.Find(new BsonDocument())
        .ForEachAsync(async (document) =>
        {
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            using (var jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(stringWriter))
            {
                var context = BsonSerializationContext.CreateRoot(jsonWriter);
                collection.DocumentSerializer.Serialize(context, document);
                var line = stringWriter.ToString();
                await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(line);
            }
        });
}
```

ORIGINAL:

These are Mongo [ObjectId's](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) and if you haven't already deserialised the document they should support a [toString](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/#ObjectId.toString) method that will return a hexadecimal string.

but if you want this applied to the whole document, using `JSON.stringify(MogoDocument)` should deserialize this for you into a plain object.